# how do I reduce the size of the video captured using camera

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

How do I reduce the size of the video captured using cordova media plugin. Current Resolution and file size for 2-minute duration in Samsung Galaxy Tab S in 3 different resolutions is mentioned below. I tried quality option in captureVideo method but that is depending on the device resolution.

(640 x 480) VGA  - [47 MB],
(1280x720)HD -   [176 MB],
(1920 x 1080)FHD - [247 MB]

Wonder how facebook live and other streaming apps work seamlessly.

Comment: did you set quality to 0? what's the size if you set the quality to 1?

Comment: Yes I tried setting quality to 0. but it will consider the least resolution possible for the device. Say for device mentioned in the above question 640x 480 is considered while setting to 0  and 1920 x 1080 for 1 . Is there any other option to reduce the video size. Native code will also help.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way of setting the resolution (even in native code), just the quality

Comment: I was not able to find any option to reduce the video size while recording.Instead I used Okhttp to transfer large files and restricted the recording size.Current issue is still open.